# How can I exhibit the evaluation of formulas in a Mathcad-like way?

Tags: equation-solving, output-formatting

[image]

How can I create a function  F that works like this:

```
 x = 2
 f1 = x^2 + 3
 f2=x+5

 F[f1]
```

> ```
> x^2 + 3 = 2^2 + 3 = 7
> ```

```
 F[f2]
```

> ```
> x + 5 = 2 + 5 = 7
> ```

Comment: Unless @Mr.Wizard has answered your question adequately, can you clarify?  I'm confused by the lack of a verb in the question title and the relationship between the green text and code.

Comment: I don't think this question needs to be closed.  As I see it the user wants to show the evaluation chain, including at least the step where symbol is "filled in" by a definition, such as `x` in `x^2 + 3`.  User: is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

First you will need to make your definitions with [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`) rather than [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html) (`=`):

```
x  := 2
f1 := x^2 + 3
f2 := x + 5
```

You can get a list of all evaluation steps using [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Trace.html) or [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TracePrint.html).  To get only the steps that transform the entire expression use the Option `TraceDepth -> 1`, and you can format with [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Row.html)

```
Row[Trace[f1, TraceDepth -> 1], "="]
```

> ```
> f1 = x^2+3 = 4+3 = 7
> ```

This is not exactly what you asked for but I hope it is close enough to help.  The additional steps are accessible with `Trace` but I could not think of a simple and robust way to use them and I can't spend more time on this right now.  For reference:

```
Trace[f1]
```

> ```
> {f1,x^2+3,{{x,2},2^2,4},4+3,7}
> ```

Comment: I think your answer might be closer to what the OP is asking for if you added a definition for his `F` along the lines of: `SetAttributes[F, HoldFirst]; F[var_Symbol] := Row[Trace[var, TraceDepth -> 1], "="]` -- providing, of course, that you think this would be robust enough to meet the OP needs.

Comment: @m_goldberg Good point.  user10833: that is indeed the way to package an expression such as this as a function.  I did not do that as I did not feel this was complete, e.g. there is no `2^2+3` step shown.