# How to display operations on list elements

Tags: list-manipulation

When applying some arithmetic operation on two lists, I'd like to display the actual operations between the elements of each list. For example, `{1, 1} + {1, -1}` would display `{1 + 1, 1 - 1}`.

With simple operations, I could just use `Trace` and pick out the part with the right form:

```
Trace[{1, 1} + {1, -1}, {_Plus, _Plus}]
(* {{1+1,1-1}} *)
```

However, this becomes really cumbersome in more complex operations. Even worse, some operations don't even show element-by-element operations within `Trace`.

```
Trace[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}.{{5, 6}, {7, 8}}]
(* {{{1,2},{3,4}}.{{5,6},{7,8}},{{19,22},{43,50}}} *)
```

This is what I actually want to display:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course I could programmatically display the element operation of the matrix multiplication above, but I have to do the same for every other matrix operations.

---

**My question is:** Is there a straightforward way to display operations on elements of two lists? Please feel free to add your own examples and make it as general as you want to.

Comment: Related: [(148)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148), [(37876)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37876)

Comment: Thanks for `TraceDepth`!

Comment: I notice you have not Accepted an answer to this.  Does anything remain unaddressed to your satisfaction?  Can I do anything to improve my answer?

Answer (score 8):

This might be "too direct" an answer, but you can try:

```
Inner[Inactive[Times], {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, Inactive[Plus]] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1*5+2*7 & 1*6+2*8 \\
 3*5+4*7 & 3*6+4*8 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Very nice and succinct! I wonder if this could be achieved (perhaps with less terseness) in older MMA versions.

Answer (score 5):

For version 9 (and possibly older versions), you can use

```
Inner[Composition[Defer, Times], {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}] // MatrixForm
```

or

```
Inner[Defer[Times@##] &, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}] // MatrixForm
```

or

```
Inner[Composition[HoldForm, Times], {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}] // MatrixForm
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers all use `Inner` to perform the specific operation of `Dot`, but these do not provide a general way to visualize results.  I cannot provide a truly general way either but I feel that this has wider application:

```
SetAttributes[show, HoldFirst]
form[expr_] := expr /. m_ /; MatrixQ@Unevaluated@m :> MatrixForm[m]
show[expr_] :=
  Row[{Defer[expr], Unevaluated[expr] /. n_?NumericQ :> Defer[n], expr}, "="] // form
```

Test:

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}.{{5, 6}, {7, 8}} // show
```

[image]

In the simpler example a possible problem appears:

```
{1, 1} + {1, -1} // show
```

[image]

This is because of the behavior:

```
"foo" + "foo" + "foo"
```

> ```
> 3 "foo"
> ```

If this is unacceptable I shall have to include special handling.

**Note:** be aware of the automatic formatting that is applied even to held expressions; see:

- [Returning an unevaluated expression with values substituted in](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7880/returning-an-unevaluated-expression-with-values-substituted-in/7882#7882)

Comment: Could you help me understand why `Unevaluated[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}.{{5, 6}, {7, 8}}] /. n_?NumericQ :> Defer[n]` would display the intermediate result?

Comment: @seismatica It makes all numeric objects inert and then evaluates it.  This means that they are effectively treated as symbols or strings.  This will not always produce the result you want but I think in sufficiently many cases to be useful it may.

Comment: But what happens to the `Unevaluated`? Would it be erased by the `ReplaceAll`? To be honest I'm not quite sure what the difference is between `Defer` and `Unevaluate`, and let's not touch the variants of `Hold`.

Comment: @seismatica You do not understand the way that `Unevaluated` works.  I didn't either for a long time.  Read the presentation I link here: [(25308)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25308).  See also this answer relating to the sister function `Evaluate`: [(46753)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46753).  These "functions" only affect the evaluation of the head directly surrounding them; one way to think about this is that `ReplaceAll` *momentarily* behaves as if it had a `HoldFirst` attribute.  As soon as the replacement is complete evaluation continues normally.

Comment: @seismatica `Unevaluated` and `Defer` do completely separate things.  `Unevaluated` momentarily modifies the way a function evaluates its arguments, while `Defer` is a special kind of `Hold` that is removed during output formatting, resulting in an expression that will evaluate if given as input.  I used it here so that you could copy, paste, and evaluate any part of the printed output.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time to explain it to me! The notebook by Mr Villegas was very helpful (shame about the author though). Also, how can one come up with the "special handling" to avoid `Times`? I feel like I've seen that question before but can't seem to search for it.

Comment: @seismatica I feel like a clod but I didn't know what became of the author until now.  Very sad. :-(  On the other matter I don't yet know as I haven't tried.  In the extreme one might have to tag each number uniquely to keep them from being seen as the same and reduced.  In some cases Blocking `Plus` and using another addition function might work, but I can easily imagine ways that would fail.

Comment: I think putting `Times` in `Block` might work (in this case). I tried to follow [your answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7880/returning-an-unevaluated-expression-with-values-substituted-in/7882#7882) in this Q&A but didn't go far. How would you set out to avoid the `Times`, even if it's just specific to this case?

Comment: @seismatica Remind me on Monday; I'll give a complete example.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, but, based on **chuy's** solution, I want to show one of the advantages of the new **V10** `Inactive`:

```
(x = Inner[Inactive[Times],
    {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}},
       Inactive[Plus]]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Activate[x, Times] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Activate[x] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice demonstration of `Inactive`!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @Mr.Wizard's answer. This should work with both numbers and symbols:

```
ClearAll[elementDisplay]
SetAttributes[elementDisplay, HoldAll]
elementDisplay[f_[arg__List]] := f @@ Function[x, Defer[x], Listable]@{arg} // MatrixForm
elementDisplay[{{1, 2}, {a, b}}.{{5, 6}, {c, d}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[listOpDisplay]
SetAttributes[listOpDisplay, HoldAll]
listOpDisplay[f_[arg__List]] := 
 Row[{Defer[f[arg]], f @@ Function[x, Defer[x], Listable]@{arg}, 
    f[arg]}, "="] /.
  m_ /; MatrixQ@Unevaluated@m :> MatrixForm@m

listOpDisplay[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}.{{5, 6}, {7, 8}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
listOpDisplay[Cross[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 1/2, 1/3}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]