# How to show matrix multiplication step by step?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Given a matrix, A:

```
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

How can I do the matrix multiplication A times A step by step?

Comment: Related: [How to display operations on list elements](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57458/125)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have *Mathematica* 10 you can use the new `Inactive` functionality

```
step1 = MatrixForm[Inner[Inactive[Times], A, A, Inactive[Plus]], TableSpacing -> {3, 3}]
```

[image]

```
step2 = Activate[step1, Times]
```

[image]

```
Activate[step2]
```

[image]

Comment: Dang, I was trying to figure out how to use `Inactivate` on `Plus` and `Times` to get this to work with `Inner`, but it wasn't working because I was placing `Inactive` at the wrong locations of my expression. +1 for getting it to work!

Answer (score 15):

You can use `HoldForm` or `Defer` with `Composition` if you are still using Pre **V10** versions:

```
MatrixForm[Inner[Composition[Defer, Times], A, A, 
                              Composition[Defer, Plus]], TableSpacing -> {3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MatrixForm[Inner[Times, A, A, Composition[HoldForm, Plus]], TableSpacing -> {3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MatrixForm[Inner[Times, A, A, Plus], TableSpacing -> {3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course, there's the **V10** syntax for `Composition` i.e. `@*` that can make the above code shorter:

```
MatrixForm[Inner[Defer@*Times, A, A, Defer@*Plus], TableSpacing -> {3, 3}]
MatrixForm[Inner[Times, A, A, Defer@*Plus], TableSpacing -> {3, 3}]
MatrixForm[Inner[Times, A, A, Plus], TableSpacing -> {3, 3}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[A, n, k, nn, aa]
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
Print["A"]
MatrixForm[A]
aa = Length[A];
Print["First step in matrix multiplication A times A"]
MatrixForm[
 Table[Flatten[
   Table[Table[
     StringJoin[{"(", ToString[A[[nn, k]]], ")", "\[CenterDot]", "(", 
       ToString[A[[k, n]]], ")", 
       If[k < aa, "+", If[n == aa, "", ","]]}], {k, 1, aa}], {n, 1, 
     aa}]], {nn, 1, aa}]]
Print["Multiply:"]
MatrixForm[
 Table[Flatten[
   Table[Table[
     StringJoin[{"(", ToString[A[[nn, k]]*A[[k, n]]], ")", 
       If[k < aa, " +", If[n == aa, "", ",   "]]}], {k, 1, aa}], {n, 
     1, aa}]], {nn, 1, aa}]]
Print["and add:"]
MatrixForm[A.A]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a symbolically pure method but it does the job if one accepts that the terms are prepended with an empty space "" and wrapped with two square brackets [ ].

```
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
B = Table[Table[""[A[[n, k]]], {k, 1, Length[A]}], {n, 1, Length[A]}];
TableForm[B.B]
```

[image: step by step matrix multiplication]

Comment: Matrix multiplication spelled out: `A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}; B = A; TableForm[
 Table[Table[Sum[A[[n, i]]*B[[i, k]], {i, 1, Length[A]}], {k, 1, Length[A]}], {n, 1, Length[A]}]]`

Answer (score 1):

One can get (more drawn out) steps with the `WolframAlpha` command:

```
WolframAlpha["{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}.{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}", 
  {{"Result", 2}, "Content"}, PodStates -> {"Result__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

[image]